# ZTE F660 Router not Forwarding Ports AT ALL

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Given I can't access admin mode with said router, I can only log in with an "installer" user that gives me access to the application submenu as well as port forwarding.

[image]

I've set my local IP address as static as well. I don't know what to do anymore. I've added all the Ports I need to forward like this...

[image]

I've set the protocol accordingly as the original page specifies, but using several websites to check if my PC is forwarding ports only returns error after error! I have no idea how to proceed! I don't think Avast! is the issue here, and my firewall has been turned off since day one. Any ideas on what I should do?